# An inequality like Riemann sum involving $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

How can I prove that for every positive integer $n$ we have

\begin{equation*}
\frac{n\pi}{4}−\frac{1}{\sqrt{8n}}<\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n−1}\sqrt{1−\frac{k^2}{n^2}}?
\end{equation*}

Comment: I would think to start by replacing the sum with the integral from 0 to n-1 and see if that works.  No guarantees.

Comment: I have thought a proof using integrals as well as trying slicing a suitable part of circle but without success. Maybe one should try to do computations with details as I was unable to find a proof.

Comment: [Euler-Maclaurin summation][1] might help  :
We have :   $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k) = \int_{1}^{n} f(x) dx + \frac{f(1)+f(n)}{2} + \int_{1}^{n} f'(x) (x - \lfloor x \rfloor - 1/2) dx $ for any decreasing $f$. Choosing $f = \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}}$ we get:
 $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{1 -\frac{k^2}{n^2} } = \int_{1}^{n}\sqrt{1 - \frac{x}{n}^2}  + \frac{1}{2} - \int_{1}^{n}( x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2} ) \frac{x}{n \sqrt{n^2 - x^2}} $.

  
  [1]: http://calculus.nctu.edu.tw/~ocw/upload/fourier/supplement/euler%20summation.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write the inequality as
$$\frac{\pi}{4} < \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2} + \frac{1}{2n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}}.$$
The left-hand side $\pi/4$ is the area of the part of the unit circle that
lies in the first quadrant (below the curve $y=f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$).
We want to interpret the right-hand side as the area of a region $D$ which
covers that quarter circle.

Note that $f$ is concave, so that its graph lies below any tangent line.
Thus the trapezoid bounded by the lines $x=a-\epsilon$ and $x=a+\epsilon$
and by the $x$ axis and the tangent line through $(a,f(a))$ will cover the
corresponding part of the circle:
$$\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} f(x) dx < 2\epsilon f(a).$$

Thus, taking $D$ to be the union of the following pieces does the trick:

- A rectangle of height 1 between $x=0$ and $x=1/2n$.
- Trapezoids as above, of width $\frac{1}{n}$ and centered at $x=k/n$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$.
- A trapezoid as above, of width $\frac{1}{2n}$ and centered at $x=1-1/4n$. This last one has area
  $$\frac{1}{2n} f(1-1/4n) = \frac{1}{2n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{16n^2}} <   \frac{1}{2n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}}.$$